# Run-time analysis of common machine learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, algorithms

Does anyone have reference to a summary of run-time analyses for common machine learning algorithms (different flavors of NN, SVMs, etc)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some superficial tables:

- The Computational Mathematics of Statistical Data Mining. [PPT](http://www.cercs.gatech.edu/iucrc08/material/agray.ppt)
- Table 1 in:

  > Chu, C. T., Kim, S. K., Lin, Y. A., Yu, Y., Bradski,
  > G. R., Ng, A. Y., & Olukotun, K. (2006). Mapreduce for machine learning on multicore. Neural
  > Information Processing Systems (pp. 281–288). [PDF](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/people/ang//papers/nips06-mapreducemulticore.pdf)

Comment: First link is dead.

Comment: Fixed broken link based on google search. However, there are multiple versions of the relevant presentation online, so this might not be an exact duplicate of the original one.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the following article: [computational complexity of machine learning algorithms](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine/learning/computational-complexity-learning-algorithms/) where I keep track of the (theoretical) complexity of learning algorithms and run time analysis based on log-log regressions.